# Constructibility of n-gon: relation between cyclotomic polynomial and field of constructible points

Tags: abstract-algebra

This post is on the constructibility of $n$-gons, where the $n$-gon is constructible iff $\phi(n)=2^a$. I believe that the combination of the two following theorems will prove the result, but I am not sure how they combine.

There are two theorems:

1. $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n):\mathbb{Q}]=\phi(n)$
2. Let $p$ be a constructible point. For some integer $n$, there exists a chain of fields

$$\mathbb{Q} = F_0 \subset F_1 \subset F_2 \subset \cdots \subset F_n = K, \text{such that}$$

- $k$ is a subfield of the field of real numbers
- the coordinates of $p$ are in $K$
- for each $i=0, \cdots,n-1$, $[F_{i+1}:F_i]$ is equal to 1 or 2.

The most important of theorem 2 is that $[F_{i+1}:F_i]=2^b$. I'm aware that $[K : \mathbb{Q}]=2^c$ is a result of theorem 2. The problem is I'm not sure how the two exactly combine, although it is clear that when they combine, the proof is obvious. How do I connect the cyclotomic polynomials, which is in the complex plane, to $[F_{i+1}:F_i]=2^b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To construct the regular n-gon we just need to now for which $n\geq 3$, the central angle $2\pi/n$ is constructible. The connections with the unity roots and the complex plane comes from here, since $2\cos (\frac{2\pi}{n})=\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{-1}$. We will need a few lemmas that uses your two theorems.

**Lemma 1**: For every $r\geq 2$ the angle $\frac{2\pi}{2^r}$ is constructible.

Hint: use induction and the bisection of the angle formed by two lines that intersect.

**Lemma 2**: Let $m$ and $n$ dos positive coprime integers. The the angle $\frac{2\pi}{mn}$ is constructible if and only if $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ and $\frac{2\pi}{m}$ are both constructible.

Hint: Use the fact that if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constructible then $s\alpha+r\beta$ are constructible for $s,r\in\mathbb{Z}$. For the reciprocal just use this fact applied to Bezout's identity.

**Lemma 3**: Let $p$ a prime number greater than $2$, $k$ a positive integer and $n:=p^k$. Then the angle $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ is constructible if and only if $k=1$ and $p=2^{2^r}+1$ for some $r\geq 0$.

**Proof**:

Lets suppose that the angle $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ is constructible, i.e the real number $c_n=\cos(2\pi/n)$ is constructible, so it implies that $[\mathbb{Q}(c_n):\mathbb{Q}]=2^{l-1}$ for some $l\geq 1$. Since we know that  $[\mathbb{Q}(c_n):\mathbb{Q}]=\frac{\phi(n)}{2}$ it implies that $$p^{k-1}(p-1)=\phi(n)=2[\mathbb{Q}(c_n):\mathbb{Q}]=2^l$$
In consequence, $k=1$ and $p=2^l+1$. If $l$ is not a power of $2$ then some odd $q$ would divide $l$ and then $l=qm$ for some even $m$. Since $q$ is odd
$$ t^q+1=(t+1)\sum_{j=0}^{q-1}(-1)^jt^j$$
and it implies
$$p=2^l+1=2^{mq}+1=(2^m+1)\sum_{j=0}^{q-1}(-1)^j2^{mj}$$
but that's impossible since $p$ is prime and $1<2^m+1<p$. Therefore exists some integer $r\geq 0$ such as $l=2^r$, and $p=2^{2^r}+1$.

Reciprocally, let's suppose that $p=2^l+1$ for some integer $l\geq 1$, and we have to prove that $c:=\cos (2\pi/p)$ is constructible. Let $s:=\sin (2\pi/p)$, $i:=\sqrt{-1}$, and consider $\zeta=c+is\in\mathbb{C}$. We know that $\zeta$ is an pth-root of unity, so $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)|\mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois extension which Galois group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{p}^*$, which order is $\phi(p)=p-1=2^l$. Also $2c=\zeta+\zeta^{-1}\in\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, so we have a field tower $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{Q}(c)\subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, and since the Galois group is cyclic, the subgroups are normal, so it follow from the second fundamental theorem of Galois theory that $$G(\mathbb{Q}(c):\mathbb{Q})\cong\frac{G(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q})}{G(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q}(c))}$$
In particular, $G(\mathbb{Q}(c):\mathbb{Q})$ is cyclic and it's order is $ord(\frac{G(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q})}{G(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q}(c))})=\frac{\phi(n)}{2}=2^{l-1}$. It follows from the Sylow theorems and the fact that is cyclic that for every $1\geq j\geq l-1$, $G(\mathbb{Q}(c):\mathbb{Q})$ has an unique normal subgroup $H_j$ with order $2^{l-1-j}$ and $H_{j+1}\subset H_j$. So we have a field tower
$$\mathbb{Q}=K_0\subset K_1\subset \cdots \subset K_{l-1}=\mathbb{Q}(c)$$ for $K_j=Fix(H_j)$ and every extension $K_{j+1}|K_j$ has degree $2$. It implies from the definition of constructibility (your second theorem), that $c$ is constructible

**Theorem**=Let $n\geq 3$ a positive integer. Then the angle $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ is constructible if and only if n is a power of $2$ or $n:=2^r p_1\cdots p_k$ where $r$ is non negative and the primes $p_i$ are different two by two and they are on the form $p_j=2^{2^{r_j}}+1$ where $r_j\geq q$ for $1\leq j\leq k$.

**Proof**

From the lemma 1 the angle $\frac{2\pi}{2^l}$ is constructible for every integer $l\geq 1$. Suppose that $n:=2^r p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$ for $r\geq 0$ and $\alpha_j\geq 1$. If the angle $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ is constructible it follows from lemma 2 it follows that every angle $\frac{2\pi}{p_j^{\alpha_j}}$ is constructible. It implies from lemma 3 that $\alpha_j=1$, $p_j=2^{2^{r_j}}+1$ for some positive integer $r_j$ for $1\leq j\leq k$.

Reciprocally, if $n:=2^r p_1\cdots p_k$ and the prime numbers $p_j$ verifies the conditions of the theorem, it follow from lemma 1 and 3 that the angles $\frac{2\pi}{2^r}$ and $\frac{2\pi}{p_j}$ are constructible. Applying the lemma 2 it concludes that the angle $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ is constructible.

Comment: Thank you! Your insight for the bi-conditional for lemma 3 was very helpful. However, how do I show that $\zeta_n$ is a constructible point? I'm still not very clear on that.

Comment: Since $c_n, s_n, i$ are constructible $\zeta_n=c_n+is_n$ is

Comment: Also, in the bi-conditional proof of lemma 3, should $c=\cos(\frac{2\pi}{p}})$?

Comment: Yes, sorry it was a typo

Comment: Also, concerning "every extension Kj+1|Kj has degree 2" Could it have degree 1? Because if a point is constructed by the intersection of two lines, then that point is in the same field, so it would have degree 2. Am I missing something?

Comment: The existence of the fields $K_j$ which this special properties is derived directly from the second theorem of Sylow